# Cannot send json to HttpPost method when there is a string parameter constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, http-post

I have no idea if this is a bug on the limitation of ASP.NET. Let's say, I have a class named Info.

```
public class Info
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Data { get; set; }

    public Info(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }
}
```

Here is the method on controller.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Post")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]Info info)
```

It works fine when I post json to the website.

```
POST /test/post HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:60002
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache

{ "Id": "1", "Data": "Test" }
```

The problem is it stop working when I add a string parameter constructor to `Info`.

```
public class Info
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Data { get; set; }

    public Info(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    // this messes things up
    public Info(string data)
    {
        // to do 
    }
}
```

My question is, is it ASP.NET limitation, is it its bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried having the constructor parameter be exactly the same as the json parameter and the variable (currently they have a different case)? Also, what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Try adding the empty/default constructor explicitly also. See if that solves your problem or not.